# How to access the url of dynamic nested route in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to generate a url like this

```
http://example.app/activate?serial=esdse3434?machine=jni9ninei9
```

I am aware nuxt file system allow dynamically nested route, [doc](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#dynamic-nested-routes)

I know how to get the name or value of the current route using `$route.params.id`, but how do I get the value of the parent route in the child route e.g

```
pages/
--| activate/
-----| _serial/
--------| _machine.vue
```

Is there a way to get the param of `_serial` inside `_machine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done like this (in `activate.vue`), no need to have any additional pages

```html
<button @click="$router.push({ path: '/activate', query: { serial: 'esdse3434', machine: 'jni9ninei9' } })">
  Generate link
</button>
```

---

EDIT on how to make it dynamic

```js
mounted() {
  this.$router.push({
    path: '/activate',
    query: { serial: this.$route.query.serial, machine: this.$route.query.machine },
  })
},
```

More info on the official docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: My question then will be how to get the value of serial and machine dynamically. I am using mounted here `mounted () {
    this.$router.push({ path: '/activate', query: { serial: '', machine: '' } })
  },`

e.g I send a user to visit a link http://localhost:3000/activate?serial=dsdwewqq&machine=wqew2q2323/activate?serial=dsdwewqq&machine=wqew2q2323. 

The value of serial and machine is dynamic and can be anything.

Comment: @xtremeCODE I already answered this in my answer + an explanation of the current approach you're trying now

Comment: yep, that's why I upvoted you @Jordan (was essentially answering how to generate the URL)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you're confusing route params with query params. Route params are separated parts of the URL using `/`. A query string is what you're looking for to create those types of URL.

If I created a directory structure the same as yours and then on mounted inside **_machine.vue**, I ran `console.log(this.$route.params)` I would get the following output:

```
{
    serial: "test",
    machine: "test2"
}
```

To use this page structure, the URL would look like `localhost:3000/activate/test/test2`.

To use query strings, you need to have a page called **activate.vue** then inside that page you need to access `$route.query.serial` and `$route.query.machine`. You would not use folders and nested pages. That's only for route params.